# Where can I get POP/IMAP settings for Windows Live Domain emails

Tags: imap, pop3, hotmail, windows-live-mail

I have setup email for my custom domain using [Windows Live Domains](https://domains.live.com/Signup/SignupDomain.aspx). I then upgraded from the Hotmail interface to the new Outlook.com interface.

I cannot seem to find the POP/IMAP settings to connect to in the Settings Sections of the new Outlook.com interface. The only instructions I could find mentioned were using the Hotmail interface, and the corresponding section does not exist in the Outlook.com redesigned settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of googling, I found the correct settings. They have been tested to work on the native Android App.

### Incoming Settings

```
Username: username@domain.com
Password: password
Port: 995
Security: Enable SSL
Server: pop3.live.com
```

### Outgoing Settings

```
Username: username@domain.com
Password: password
Server: smtp.live.com
Port: 587
Security: Enable TLS
```

To setup a custom domain email using the new outlook.com interface, do the following:

1. Go to [Windows Live Domains](https://domains.live.com/Signup/SignupDomain.aspx) and signup with your domain
2. Verify your domain by changing the DNS entries
3. Create a new email account on that domain
4. Login to hotmail.com with that account.
5. Upgrade to the new Outlook.com interface by going to options and clicking "Upgrade"

There are no IMAP settings available for hotmail/outlook/windows live domain emails.

In outlook 2013/Windows 8.1 I had to go to account settings->more settings->advanced and click uses encryption and set the encryption type to auto.

Answer (score 1):

[Exchange Active Sync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_ActiveSync) is [currently possible](http://email.about.com/od/Outlook.com/f/What-Are-The-Outlook-Com-Exchange-ActiveSync-Settings.htm) and IMAP is [promised in the future](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/internet/news/microsoft-says-outlookcom-imap-support-coming-promises-better-mac-support-253444) (which as far as I can tell still hasn't arrived):

> Outlook.com Exchange ActiveSync server address: m.hotmail.com
>
> Outlook.com Exchange ActiveSync domain: (leave empty)
>
> Outlook.com Exchange user name: Your full Outlook.com email address (not an alias)
>
> Outlook.com Exchange ActiveSync password: Your Outlook.com password
>
> Outlook.com Exchange ActiveSync TLS/SSL encryption required: yes
>
> (from about.com)

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I was trying to set up a hotmail account which has a custom domain in Boxer App on iOS! :)